# nextjs with multiple templates based on website url

Tags: next.js13

I want to write my next project in NextJs with multiple templates. Imagine like a WP site where u can select the template in your admin area.
I think this is not so easy as it looks like. Managing all the imports and being still SEO friendly.
Any idea where i can start on focus?

I thought first making different directories for different templates but the imports are the problem.

Comment: I've been researching this for a very long time and all I can find is "nothing".
pls can help anyone